# vim ruby mismatch on Mac High Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos, vim, macos-high-sierra

I recently upgraded my Mac to **High Sierra**

After the upgrade, Macvim (mvim) stopped working because (I assume) HighSierra upgraded ruby to 2.3, and mvim is using ruby 2.0.

Following is the error I am getting

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib

Referenced from: `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-134/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/../MacOS/Vim`

Do I need to compile vim again or is there any way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try changing the dyld to the new one in the Vim binary with `install_name_tool`...

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem.

Comment: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/952

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me. YMMV

`brew uninstall --purge macvim
brew install macvim`

[amended] Regarding the `upgrade` alone option, that may work if you don't have the current version already. The `--purge` forces a removal and complete reinstall. 
Also, the `build from source` option, while it may work, you now own your own mac-vim static snapshot and need to maintain it manually as the app evolves. 
I'd avoid building from source unless you have very specific needs.

Comment: Did the trick for me as well.  Updating from GUI as suggested in other post did not work for me.  Thanks, Bruce!

Comment: Yep, this one helped me as well! But, I should add that I also had to run GUI Xcode app itself at least once before installing vim, since it needed to install some additional components. See: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/546

Comment: This works for `vim` too, if one insn't using `macvim`.

Comment: In the entire history of the git source for `brew` I can't find mention of a `--purge` option. Did you mean `--force`?

Comment: Um, yep, must have been. (--force) Many apologies. @skrat

Answer (score 14):

First find where is the right libruby path, mine is: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib`

It is common that the version has changed.

Find out where the absolute path of vim is:

```
$ which vim
vim: aliased to your-path-of-vim
```

change dyld:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib your-path-of-vim
```

Comment: This worked with a minor difference. Instead of using `which vim`, use the path indicated in error. In my case, it was `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-151/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/../MacOS/Vim`

Answer (score 12):

```
➜  ~ vim
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried brew uninstall install update... All failed. And `install_name_tool` works for me.

```
install_name_tool -change /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Comment: I was in the same situation with none of the other solutions working, but the install_name_tool worked for me, thank you!

Comment: After tried, I got this error: error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: input file: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-143/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim is not a Mach-O file

Comment: This worked for me, but it was a slightly different binary location.
`install_name_tool -change /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-151/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/MacVim`
and
`install_name_tool -change /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-151/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`

Comment: Important to note that `/usr/local/bin/vim` should be replaced with whatever the error says is the referencing file. In my case, it was `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-151/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/../MacOS/Vim`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
$ brew update

$ brew upgrade macvim
```

actual command output:

```
[bin]$ brew upgrade macvim
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
macvim 8.0-142
==> Upgrading macvim --with-override-system-vim
==> Downloading https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/archive/snapshot-142.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/tar.gz/snapshot-142
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --with-macarchs=x86_64 --enable-perlinterp --enable-rubyinterp --enable-tclinterp --enable-ter
==> make
  /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-142: 2,147 files, 34.2MB, built in 3 minutes 15 seconds
[bin]$
```

Answer (score 3):

What helped in my case was:

```
brew link --overwrite vim
```

In your case, it might be useful to use the same command for MacVim

```
brew link --overwrite macvim
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to use `brew upgrade macvim` an error was raised and the failed. What worked for me is to open the `MacVim` in a normal window (not a iTerm or terminal) the graphic version noticed that a newer version is available and asked if I want to update. Clicked `yes, please` and done. `macvim` in terminal or iTerm works just fine (as well as the "window" version).