# I can not use the command gvim in terminal

Tags: macos

When I entry gvim,it will be:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.0.dylib

Referenced from: `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.0-126/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim`
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
How can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently upgraded your *macOS*? Maybe you're using a different Ruby version (**2.3** instead of the **2.0** you were supposed to have).

You can either try to update your current version:

```
brew update
brew upgrade gvim
```

Or directly uninstall and re-install gvim:

```
brew uninstall --purge gvim
brew install gvim
```

If any of those solutions works fine for you, I've also found a similar case on Stackoverflow with your same issue [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278449/vim-ruby-mismatch-on-mac-high-sierra).